# How to highlight a selected row in *ngFor?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, angular, html-table

I couldn't find something that will help me to solve this issue in Angular2. I'd like to set a css class when I select a row. (without using jQuery)

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-condensed table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Website</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let item of companies"  (click)="selectedCompany(item, $event)">
            <td>{{item.name}}</td>
            <td>{{item.email}}</td>
            <td>{{item.website}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>   
</table>
```

I'm using Angular2 final release

Answer (score 29, accepted):

There are plenty of solutions to do this, one of them is you can store the current company when clicked.

In the `*ngFor` you check if the current item is the `currentCompany` and you add the class `highlighted` or whatever class you wish if its the same company.

```
export class TableComponent {

  public currentCompany;

  public selectCompany(event: any, item: any) {

    this.currentCompany = item.name;
  }

}
```

And then on your template:

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of companies" (click)="selectCompany($event, item)" 
 [class.highlighted]="item.name === currentCompany">
```

--

Another solution if you wish to have multiple highlighted companies you can add a property `highlighted` to your item. Then on `selectCompany()` you just set the property to true. On your check you do `[class.highlighted]="item.highlighted"`.

Comment: I didn't realize you could bind to [class.someclass] until now.  I haven't come across it in any of the Angular documentation.  That was the answer for me as well.

Comment: This helped me out. You can also provide a comparison function in the class binding, if you want to keep as much logic out of the templates as possible.

Comment: Thank you for your guide. In my case for example, it worked out assigning the object to my variable and comparing the whole object without putting like "item.name"

Comment: Multiple highlighted companies was the key for my problem. Solution worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

I know this was answered a while ago, but to expand on the accepted answer, you could also use [ngClass]="{'class_name': item.id === currentCompany  }". The table hover may need to be removed as it may hide the background color change

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of companies" (click)="selectCompany($event, item)" [ngClass]="{'class_name': item.id === currentCompany  }" >
```

Then css

```
.class_name{ background-color: yellow; }
```