# highlight multiple table rows with CSS class

Tags: css, angular, datatables

I am trying to highlight multiple rows when the user clicks them based on [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40378752/1634753). My console.log outputs correctly every time a row is clicked, the rows never change color like I expected from the style. What am I missing?

**My HTML**

```
<table datatable [dtOptions]="dtOptionsComp" [dtTrigger]="dtTriggerComp" class="row-border hover">
    <thead><tr><th>ID</th><th>Name</th></tr></thead>
    <tbody>
  <tr *ngFor="let d of companylist" (click)="selectCompany($event, d)" [class.highlighted]="d.highlighted">
    <td>{{d.id}}</td><td>{{d.name}}</td>
  </tr></tbody>
</table>
```

**My component**

```
  public selectCompany(event: any, item: any) {
    this.selectedCompanyList.push(item.id);
    console.log(this.selectedCompanyList+" whee");
    item.highlighted=true;
  }
```

**My CSS**

```
.table tr.highlighted td {
    background-color:#123456 !important;
    color: white;
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using class directive so you need to use class which match the directive class like this

```
.highlighted {
    background-color:#123456 !important;
    color: white;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `td` from style, as style is applying to `tr`

```css
.table tr.highlighted {
    background-color:#123456 !important;
    color: white;
  }
```

Please try above!

Answer (score 0):

Use this css.
Remove . from table because it is not class. you use table tag and remove td because you want tr highlighted not td.

```
table tr.highlighted {
    background-color:#123456 !important;
    color: white;
  }
```